# Should I make lambdas static?

Tags: lambda, c++11

If I have a function that defines a lambda, will the lamda be 'constructed' every time the function is called? Should I make it static to prevent that?

```
void func(int x)
{
    static auto lambda = [&x](int y) -> bool {
        // ...
    };
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, don't make it static, as it captures a local variable by reference.

I have no idea what the cost of constructing a lambda is. If you suspect it to be a performance problem: benchmark.

Comment: Oh, right. What if it hadn't captured the variable by reference?

Comment: If the lambda is big enough to warrant these worries, you could just make it a global function and pass the captured value as an additional argument.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: It's not big, I was just curious.

Comment: All this is implementation defined, but sane implementations will make it as cheap as possible for you. gcc for example seems to have a specially named function (like main::{lambda()#1}::operator()() const), and the lambda object itself is just a function pointer to it, which on invocation gets a pointer to the local stackframe passed. Within the lambda, all "reference captured" variables will then be offsets to that stack frame, while value captured will get special different offsets in the same stack frame, that will be filled at the moment where the lambda is created.

Comment: This also usually makes it undesireable to have them being static, since then -- when capturing by value -- they would always have the values at first function invocation.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: Thanks for the info. Your comment would have been a very good answer actually. :)